# Splicing two dimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this 2d array and like to splice or unset a,b,c,d  if  d is older than 30 days. 
Completely new to php arrays any help much appreciated.

```
Array 
(
    [0] => Array  (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )
    [1] => Array  (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
        )   
)


foreach($arr as $a) { 
        if($a[3] + 30 < date) {
          //??? 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for the unset function?

Comment: Unset `a,b,c,d` or unset that entire array element from the parent array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($arr as $index => $a) { 
  if($a[3] + 30 < date) {
    unset($arr[$index]);
  }
}
```

(And me, myself, and I would use associative arrays to handle it more comfortable, cause human readable)

Comment: I would also hesitate to use foreach if you're going to remove elements from the array you're foreaching. I've forgotten why. I'm getting old.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using the standard date_diff function and the DateTime object. date_diff can also give you difference in other denominations than days. I usually prefer using standard functions since it has support for more cases such as time zones.

--

```
    <?php

$d1=new DateTime("2016-03-22");
$d2=new DateTime("2015-03-23");
$d3=new DateTime("2015-03-24");
$d4=new DateTime("2015-03-25");
$today= new DateTime();

$arr = array(
    array  (
            $d1,
            $d2,
            $d3,
            $d4,
        ),
    array  (
            $d4,
            $d2,
            $d3,
            $d1
        )
);

$count=0;
foreach ($arr as &$a) { 
    echo "Element" . $count . ": \r\n";
    //print_r(date_diff($a[3], $today));
    $difference = date_diff($a[3], $today);
    if ($difference->days > 30 ){
        echo "Removing. \r\n";
        unset($arr[$count]);

    }
    else{
        echo "Not removing. \r\n";
    }
    $count++;
}

print_r($arr); 

?>
```

--

Output:

```
Element0: Removing. 
Element1: Not removing. 

// Array[0] is removed.
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-03-25 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York ) [1] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-03-23 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York ) [2] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2015-03-24 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York ) [3] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2016-03-22 00:00:00 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => America/New_York ) ) )
```